# Do you say "keli" or "kelim" for safek kelim together with one non safek keli?

Tags: halacha, blessing, mikvah-ritual-bath

If I [tovel](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-containers-tevilas.htm) (immerse in a ritual bath) a glass or metal pot, I recite a blessing first, as for many a mitzvah. The blessing ends "vetzivanu al tevilat keli", "commanded us about toveling a VESSEL". If I tovel *multiple* glass or metal pots, the blessing ends "vetzivanu al tevilat kelim", "commanded us about toveling VESSELS". However, if I tovel a porcelain vessel, I don't recite any blessing at all, since the porcelain dish only *possibly* requires toveling. Now suppose I tovel a glass pot *and* a porcelain dish. Do I say "vetzivanu al tevilat kelim" or "…keli"?

Comment: -1: egregious violation of http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1606

Comment: @msh210, I don't think this question would make any sense to an English speaker without knowledge of jewish halacha even without the use of Hebrew terminology.

Comment: AniYodeya, I've edited it so the general populace of anglophone people with some (but perhaps not extensive) knowledge of halacha has a better chance of understanding it.

Comment: Ani -- I think the question makes a *lot* of sense, as currently phrased. +1 for an interesting question, well-phrased ( cc @msh210 )

Comment: The word tovel is never translated...

Comment: AniYodeya, I linked to an explanation instead of including one. But you're right: it would be better included. By all means [edit] your post to that effect!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Aruch Hashulchan in Yo'd siman 120 siff 22 brings from the 'gedolei achronim' that there is no real requirement to make the bracha in singular tense. He adds that the minhag was in fact to also say al tvilas keilim even on one keli.

Whether or not you choose to follow this practice, I have seen that at least in a case such as yours, his opinion is good enough to rely upon and say al tvilas keilim.